# Evaluate $ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{x^8 + 1} dx$ using Residual Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Need to evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{x^8 + 1}dx $$

I'm having trouble finding the poles.

I was trying to do this before and got that the poles in the upper plane occurred at $e^\frac{i\pi}{8}$,  $e^\frac{3i\pi}{8}$, $e^\frac{5i\pi}{8}$, $e^\frac{7i\pi}{8}$. I don't know if this is right.

I know once I find the poles I have to use the equation 
$$ Res(f; z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q'(z)}$$ where $f = \frac{z^4}{z^8+1}$, $ P = z^4$ and $Q' = 8z^7$ and $z$ is a pole of $f$

The book got the answer $$\frac{\pi}{4}\biggl(sin\frac{3\pi}{8}\biggr)^{-1}$$

Any help would be appreciated.